# How to host a Rest WCF in Azure?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest

I am trying to host my rest based WCF service in the azure using a web role, I am using the following code snippet to create the host but getting the message 
FORBIDDEN 403: ACCESS IS DENIED. I am not able to figure out what is going wrong.

Is there possibility of any other issue which I may not be figuring out?

```
private void CreateServiceHost()
            {
                RoleInstanceEndpoint externalEndPoint = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["LeEndpoint"];
                var baseaddress = String.Format("http://{0}:{1}",externalEndPoint.IPEndpoint.Address,externalEndPoint.IPEndpoint.Port);
                var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), new Uri(baseaddress));
                var binding = new WebHttpBinding();
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1),binding,baseaddress);
                host.Open();
            }
```

Comment: Please, edit your C# code with `code` tags

Comment: I don't believe you can self-host in Azure due to the service fabric assigning IP's and so forth. Try creating the service declaratively, i.e., with this tutorial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlem/archive/2010/04/26/wcf-rest-and-url-rewriting-with-windows-azure.aspx